# Deploying a Node App that uses Node-Watcher

Tags: node.js, deployment, offline, intranet

I've just finished developing my Node app that uses [node-watch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-watch) to actively monitor a specific folder on my intranet network and parse CSV data into a database table as soon as someone drops a CSV file in the monitored folder.

I could test it successfully in my machine (I didn't need to install this package globally) and it's working just fine. Now is time to deploy it to the production server on the Intranet and due to information protection standards, this server has no access to the internet.

I've copied my entire app folder including node_modules to the server. The application successfully started and is running but nothing happens (neither errors) when I drop files into the monitored folder. Maybe node-watch is not a pure JS module but I can't run NPM Install on this server as it has no access to internet.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Could not find an easy solution to overcome this problem. It was easier working with the server team to open internet access to the service account that is running the node process. Once we do that I executed NPM INSTALL and re-installed all dependencies on the server. It's working now.